# clang: error: unsupported option '--ObjC'

Tags: ios, xcode

For some reason I am getting a linker error when I add '--ObjC' to my Other Linker Flags in my Xcode project. If I remove this flag, I am not able to load one of my table views and get the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[AMTableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:7344
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

Am I right in believing this is caused by the lack of --ObjC?

So when I add the flag back in (its actually being pulled in with -$(inherited), because cocoapods told me to bring it in), I get a linker error:

```
Ld /Users/jimmy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AptTin-anlnlphskgbkbydlukhsoqjapwpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/myapp normal x86_64
    cd /Users/jimmy/Desktop/AptTin
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/jimmy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AptTin-anlnlphskgbkbydlukhsoqjapwpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jimmy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AptTin-anlnlphskgbkbydlukhsoqjapwpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/jimmy/Desktop/AptTin -filelist /Users/jimmy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AptTin-anlnlphskgbkbydlukhsoqjapwpl/Build/Intermediates/AptTin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AptTin.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/myapp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 --ObjC -lPods-AFNetworking -lPods-AMSlideOutController -lPods-DACircularProgress -lPods-HexColors -lPods-LBBlurredImage -lPods-MBProgressHUD -lPods-MWPhotoBrowser -lPods-PSTCollectionView -lPods-SDWebImage -lPods-TSMessages -framework Accelerate -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreGraphics -framework ImageIO -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreLocation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AssetsLibrary -framework MessageUI -framework ImageIO -framework CoreData -framework MapKit -framework QuartzCore -framework Crashlytics -framework CoreGraphics -framework FacebookSDK -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jimmy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AptTin-anlnlphskgbkbydlukhsoqjapwpl/Build/Intermediates/AptTin.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AptTin.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/myapp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jimmy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AptTin-anlnlphskgbkbydlukhsoqjapwpl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/myapp

clang: error: unsupported option '--ObjC'
```

What am I missing? What exactly happens with the --ObjC flag?

Comment: Have you started the project with cocoapods or integrated cocoapods into existing project?

Comment: I added cocoapods in by creating a podfile in my directory and doing pod install

Answer (score 2):

The issue is incorrect spelling of linker flag. I've just checked in my project, it should be '-ObjC' with one dash, but not two.
Here is additional information about the flag:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1490/_index.html
This is description from Apple:

> Passing the -ObjC option to the linker causes it to load all members
>   of static libraries that implement any Objective-C class or category.
>   This will pickup any category method implementations. But it can make
>   the resulting executable larger, and may pickup unnecessary objects.
>   For this reason it is not on by default